# Unintended resubmission of attached file in django admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am working on a simple application to store sets of collected datapoints into a dataset using a Django app. I am using the admin interface to handle CRUD management of the dataset objects.

The problem happens in the change view when, for example, I try to rename an existing dataset with existing datapoints, which could be well over 1000. I get the error message 'Please submit 1000 or fewer forms'. It sounds like all of the datapoints are getting POSTed again, when all I want to do is just rename the dataset. There is no file attached to the form when this error occurs.

More background on the app:

- When adding/changing a Dataset object, the app needs to be able to accept an optional CSV file upload, create Datapoint objects for each row, and associate those datapoints with the dataset. If no file is present, the change view should update the other fields if there are changes.

Why is the datapoints file being uploaded again when the only change is the dataset name? How could I change the app so that the datapoints file is not resubmitted?

The behavior that results in this error:

- In the admin list view, click the 'add dataset' button
- Provide a name for the dataset, attach a CSV file with datapoints, click save button
- From the admin list view, select the dataset that was just created
- Change the name of the dataset, click save button

In `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Dataset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Datapoint(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Dataset)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    humidity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('timestamp',)
        unique_together = ('dataset','timestamp',)
```

In `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError

from .forms import UploadFileForm
from .models import Dataset, Datapoint

from csv import DictReader
from datetime import datetime

class DatapointInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Datapoint
    readonly_fields = ('timestamp', 'temperature', 'humidity',)

class DatasetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UploadFileForm

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['name', 'datapoints_file']}),
    ]

    inlines = [DatapointInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'datapoints_file' in request.FILES:
            datapoints_file = request.FILES['datapoints_file']
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    if not obj.id:
                        obj.full_clean()
                        obj.save()
                    for row in DictReader(datapoints_file, delimiter=','):
                        row['timestamp'] = datetime
                            .strptime(row['timestamp'],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
                            .strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                        row['dataset'] = obj
                        datapoint = Datapoint(**row)
                        datapoint.full_clean()
                        datapoint.save()
            except ValidationError as e:
                raise e
            except IntegrityError as e:
                raise e
        else:
            obj.save()

admin.site.register(Dataset, DatasetAdmin)
```

In `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    datapoints_file = forms.FileField(required=False)
```